# Get value from Parameter name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, server, provisioning, pppoe

I'm trying to set up an automatic provisioning with ACS server that uses JavaScript to interact with the CPE. The CPE shows the parameters on list like this:

`"DeviceID.Manufacturer" TP-Link`
`"InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.UpTime" 629`
`"InternetGatewayDevice.ManagementServer.EnableCWMP" true`

[image: Search in server]

For my automatic provisioning i want to use a parameter that it's stored in the server and not in the CPE, then do a simple IF to check if the value is right, the parameters are these two to be more precise.

`"InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.3.WANPPPConnection.1.Username" pppoe1`
`"InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.3.WANPPPConnection.1.Password" password1`

I'm using Tags that are stored in the server to compare, but tags are stored like this (with boolean):

`"Tags.pppoe1" true`

`"Tags.password1" true`

[image: Tag search]

The text after "Tags." will change for every different CPE, so i want to store the value that comes after "Tags." and then compare it with the value of `"InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.3.WANPPPConnection.1.Username"` and `"InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.3.WANPPPConnection.1.Password"`.

Is such thing possible? The software doesn't let me store "Tags" as strings, only boolean.

I tried this and similar variations, but I can't extract the value of what comes after "Tags." in any case.

```
let routerPpp = declare("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.3.Username", {value: 1});

let TagPpp = declare("Tags.*", {value: 1});

if (TagPpp !== routerPpp) {
 declare("InternetGatewayDevice.WANDevice.1.WANConnectionDevice.1.WANPPPConnection.3.Username"), {value: now}, {value: TagPpp};
}
```